# Invalid syntax for equality symbol

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Sorry it won't take my code due to some spacing issue, the toast is so fast I can't read it so screw it.

```
 File "setup.py", line 9
    executables = executables
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

BUT in the console in points to the equality symb

EDIT: setup.py contents:

```
import cx_Freeze
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("daywage.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
  name="wage calculator",
  options={"build_exe":{"packages":["daywage"],
  executables = executables
)
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of your setup.py file?

Comment: I sure I'm going to try Sir!

Comment: import cx_Freeze executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("daywage.py")] cx_Freeze.setup( name="wage calculator", options={"build_exe":{"packages":["daywage"], executables = executables )

Comment: Lol and please try to picture it with the correct spacing. I still really want a solution for this method of compiling. Since this post I have tried to compile it with a C compiler and of course it can never find the headers that are sitting right there. I'm not new to computer science but I'm relatively new to programming, unless batch counts lol

Comment: I tried to upvote you Tomas but it wouldn't allow it. My apologies sir.

Comment: I've edited it into your question and tried to guess the layout. Is that what you've got? If so, you're missing some closing braces `}`. Each opening `{` brace needs to have a matching `}`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Tomas. I'm gonna compare the two sets and let you know. Thank you in advance and again.

Comment: Okay I'm going to try and discover where the closing brace goes because where I put it, the syntax error has shifted to the left and points to the 's' in executables

Comment: Alright Tomas, I cave. Um, I moved the closing brace into ungodly positions and still a syntax error.

Comment: Try this: `options={"build_exe":{"packages":["daywage"]}},` - if it still fails, post what you've got now in setup.py (preferably by editing the question, if it lets you do that).

Comment: WOAH! like ALOT of things just happened! COOL! Im gonna analyze the result. Heads up we are making progress however something is still amiss. Thank you Tomas, this here is good for me in ways you couldn't imagine!

Comment: Okay before I go bothering a REAL programmer I'm gonna take the errors suggestion and install pywin32